# how to pass model name in scheduled action ODOO

Tags: odoo

Did there is any need to pass model name in **scheduled action** in **odoo** ...without **model name** when called function and print ****s**elf.nam**e****  it gives false

Answer (score 0):

It is required to pass a model name for schedule action, if your function is outside of the model, you can add that function in one of the model i.e `res.company`.